# Firefox wants to record video/audio

Tags: security, firefox-for-android

I have an Xperia Z5, running 7.1.1.

When I browse the web using Firefox, I keep getting requests from Firefox to record audio and take photos/videos. Both requests always happen together, in that order. I can't think of any reason why it would need to, but it does seem to happen only when I'm on pages with a lot of ads. I deny it every time, of course, but I don't tell it not to ask again, because I want to know when a request comes through.

So, my question is, is this normal? Could ads get Firefox to record video and audio, and if so, why would they? Or, could this instead be evidence of malware/a compromised device?

Answer (score 0):

When the pop-up appears, there would be an option of "Dont ask me again", check that and it will never appear again.
And if for some reasons you need that allowed later, you can give it permission by going to **Settings**>**Apps**>**Firefox**>**Permissions**, switch on the permission for particular service you need.